# Clone or copy JAXB XML block

Tags: java, jaxb

I need your help please. I’m generating an XML file using JAXB. The client request that I need to do is, when retrieving data (from data base) to set into JAXB objects I have to check one of the element values. For example:

```
<id>123</id>
<Code>X22</Code>
**<location>A1-2-3</location>**
```

If the location value is as the above I have to change it to A1, A2 and A3 and set to location attribute cloning the block like example below.
First copy

```
<id>123</id>
<Code>X22</Code>
<location>A1</location>
```

Second copy

```
<id>123</id>
<Code>X22</Code>
**<location>A2</location>**
```

Third copy

```
<id>123</id>
<Code>X22</Code>
**<location>A3</location>**
```

And set it into the same XML. My problem is that I can copy the blocks, but when I’m changing the location value it changes in all blocks, as I’m a beginner so please, help me if you can.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** I'm the author of [JAXB2-Basics](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics) which includes the [JAXB2 Copyable Plugin](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/Copyable+plugin).

You can use the [Copyable Plugin](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/Copyable+plugin) to achieve this. This plugin ganarates nice `clone` and `copy...` methods which can be used to deep copy your JAXB structures.

This is how it works.

- First you have to [enable the `-Xcopyable` plugin in your build](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics/wiki/Using-JAXB2-Basics-Plugins).
- You'll also need to add a `org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics-runtime` dependency.
- Your generated classes will get the `clone()` and `copyTo(...)` methods.
- The simples would be to use `clone()`, just clone the whole thing and change the values you need to change.
- A more advanced approach would be writing a `CopyStrategy` and use `myJaxbObject.copyTo(null, otherInstance, myCopyStrategy)` to "copy into" the `òtherInstance` with that strategy. The strategy can decide which values to copy and do some basic transformation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Ive resole it in another way, but your solution is one of the best. Thanks again.